# Rails default information page could not be displayed in IE (Windows 8.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started the rails web server as below.

`C:\Users\Jake> rails server`

A large description is printed (as expected and without error messages) and then the curser is returned:

```
Usage:
  rails new API_PATRH [options]

Options:
  <options were displayed>

Runtime options:
  <options were displayed>

Rails options:
  <options were displayed>

Description:
  <description for 'rails new' command>

Example:
  <example for 'rails new' command>

C:\Users\Jake>
```

Does this means the server stopped? Now if I open the default information page `http://localhost:3000` IE returns the message that it could not be displayed. Are there any settings I need to change in IE?

Comment: this is nothing to do with IE - what was the output from running `rails server`?

Comment: Updated the output of `rails server`. Not able to copy the full output, hence given the format instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't running `rails server` from a Rails application folder.

`cd` into the folder of a valid Rails application and run `rails server` from there.